# Is it possible to stop a program in Python?

Tags: python

If I had a code like this:

```
a=input('#something')
while True:
    if a == 0:
        #Stop the program here
```

How would I end the program?

Thanks

Comment: `Ctrl + C` in terminal.

Comment: CTRL C in terminal, CTRL D , CTRL Z in linux etc

Comment: On the off chance that you really just want to exit the loop, that’s `break`.

Comment: And note that it'll only ever exit or break if you're using Python 2, which automatically evaluates input given with `input()`, as you're looking for an integer there and not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you usually do it this way:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

If there's an error you can indicate that by passing a string as in [`sys.exit("oops!")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit).